# OPENMDAO: Do I need to activate openmdao 1.6.3 just like what I did in version 0.9.5?

Tags: openmdao

I am now trying to modify "webcam-pulse-detector" which makes use of openmdao 
and it failed in openmdao for two versions.

In version 0.9.5, it reports import error "no module named traits.api" and in the newest version 1.6.3, it reports error "ImportError: No module named datatypes.api", which is because of openmdao does't activate yet.

So how can I activate openmdao version 1.6.3 just like in version 0.9.5 by typing in "OPENMDAO/Scripts/activate" ?
   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to activate openmdao > 1.0. In older versions we relied on a virtual-env install system, but that not the case any more. So now you just install it into whatever python environment you want (like your standard one).

However, web-cam-pulse-detector was written with an older version of OpenMDAO < 1.0, and it won't work strait away in the newer version of the code. Some updates to the components will need to be made to support the new api. This [conversion guide](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.6.3/conversion-guide/conversion.html) can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that if you want to run the code directly instead of using the pre-built binaries, that you do so from the no-openmdao branch:

https://github.com/thearn/webcam-pulse-detector/tree/no_openmdao